# Can developers build a self code push server using MS Code Push service?

Tags: cordova, code-push

These days I'm using MS Code Push service,it saves time to update my cordova applications. I'm wonder if it's possible to build our own code push server other than using github or MS account?

Comment: Hey, I'm not able to get an update using code push.Can you help me with that? I'm using cordova for ios on mac. Everything latest.I'm getting errors.

Answer (score 4):

It's certainly possible to reverse-engineer the server by looking at our client plugins, but currently, we don't have a turnkey way to author or spin up your own self-hosted instance of CodePush. We are interested in making this possible down the road, but we have been focusing on improving the cloud-hosted solution first. I'd love to chat with you more about your requirements / motivations for wanting to create your own server. Email me (joncart@microsoft.com) if you're interested in chatting further.

Comment: Would Microsoft sign a BAA for codepush? I can see this as a reason to self-host.

Comment: The biggest motivation is for security. CodePush appears to create a complete backdoor to all of our users' private data. MS's privacy policy is less than ideal (e.g. http://www.networkworld.com/article/2956574/microsoft-subnet/windows-10-privacy-spyware-settings-user-agreement.html). No offense intended towards you or your team. You've created a really stellar library! But this is a major security issue.

Comment: may be there some update about creating / using existing some brand server rather than appcenter?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can deploy your own version of `Electrode - Over the Air Server` it is from `Walmart`.

- It is an `open source` project.
- Microsoft(tm) Code Push compatible server.

You can find it [Electrode](http://www.electrode.io/docs/what_is_electrode.html)[image: Electrode OTA]

Answer (score 3):

For those who are interested in custom implementation of code-push server you could probably take a look at https://github.com/lisong/code-push-server implementation of the server. 
While it is not officaialy supported by MS it is promised to work with current versions of Microsoft code-push CLI and SDK's.